# is it haram to prove the world that you are worthy by becoming successful one day

Tags: halal-haram

I am a student and I've been going through a lot in my life(mental illness) and i have the worst reputation( a very dumb and lazy kid) and now i have the feeling in my mind to prove everyone wrong by becoming successful one day(maverick entrepreneur). is this intention haram because. can someone please elaborate on this topic

Comment: Why do you think it would be haram?

Comment: if i become successful it might hurt the others and  make them jealous. wont this bring sins to me